# Layered Navigation: Select all checkbox

Tags: magento-2.1, layered-navigation, checkbox

[image]

I am using magento 2.1
In layered navigation, I want to display select all same as below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Magento default does not provide this. You can use any ready made extension like: https://www.manadev.com/layered-navigation-filters-multiple-select-magento-2

Comment: Hi Pawan, How can I add checkbox and Select all same as 2nd screenshot.

Comment: Have you checked link I add in comment ?

Comment: I already used this extension but it doesn't show any checkbox.